# CSS files outside of /static/css folder in Spring Boot

Tags: css, spring-boot

Can I use css files outside of `/static/css` folder in the Spring Boot application? Also, I wish the same for javascript files, I need them outside `/static/js` folder. I will place them inside the static folder but outside `/css` and `/js`.
For example, I wish: `/static/my_custom_folder_for_css_and_js`
What do I need to configure in spring boot? I already tried in the application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/static/**
```

Comment: You should not need a custom configuration if you put your static files in the `/resources/static/` folder, just access then via `/my_custom_folder_for_css_and_js/main.js`  ref: [static-content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content)

Comment: @DirkDeyne Thank you. I deleted `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` and used `/name_of_folder`, now it's working